# Soundcloud: how to edit widget properties

Tags: jquery, widget, soundcloud

I m in troubles with the sondcloud widget. I would like to modify it to get a more personal design. For example, moving the title and the artist to the midle, removing the play botton... something like that. So, I have been all day breaking my head but I m not able to find a solution. I have try to select the elements thought jquery but it is an iframe and it doesnt let me..

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The only solution would be to create the player yourself using SoundManager2 (what SoundCloud's player is using) and SoundCloud's REST API to get the direct link to the mp3 you wish to play (along with other metadata like artist, title, length, comments, and direct link to waveform png).